# What do the different colors of my branches is gitHub mean?

Tags: github, branch

In GitHub, I see different colors for my branches, when I go to: [Insights] - [Networks]. Some are in `blue`, others in `green`. I cannot find an explanation.

[image]

Does anyone know what the different colors mean? Are there other flavors? Like red, orange, purple...

Answer (score 2):

It's called `merge commit`.

If you are only one using it, I think it happens after you edit something directly on github and commit it (let's say you are using `master` branch). And then locally, do `git pull` which merges changes from github's `master` to your's master. And when you push changes using `git push`, github represents it as `merge commit`.

EDIT:

What I mean by `merge commit`, you can click on the black dot:

[image: First image]

And it will open commit with files changed and such, but on right, you can read:

[image: Second]

Comment: Just to make sure: is the green one or the blue one the `merge commit`?

Comment: I didn't figure out what is `blue` one or why does it happen, but made dummy repo to test and I only got green one. `Merge commit` is a kind of commit that merges two branches. It is same as if you would create some branch to test something called `develop` for example, switched to `master branch` and merged `master` with `develop`. On your picture, you can click on black dot that combines green one and black, and you would see that commit created has 2 parents(black dot is merge commit).

Comment: They all have two parents. I clicked on the black dots for a bunch of them and did some research, but nothing sticks out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, though it was not necessary. I got you in the first place. As I said, I did click on the black dot to get more info. Though for both the `green` and the `blue` commits, I have two parents. And, as I said, nothing else sticks out either.

Comment: I dont understand meaning of "nothing else sticks out either" . Do you mean that at black dot, and green line dot, everything is same, there are no differences ?

Comment: What I mean is, that if I click on a black dot where a green branch is merging with the master I see two parents and when I click on a black dot where a blue branch is merging with the master I see two parents. Everything is the same, so I still have no clue what the difference is between green and blue.

Comment: I see now. You've asked why are some green and some blue. I assume green ones represent that you added something, and blue ones that you modified something ?

Comment: That is indeed my question. In both green and blue ones I sometimes add new files to the repository. So that doesn't seem to be the distinction either.